# Zombie.js Button not enabling

Tags: html, testing, zombie.js

Currently I'm trying to use zombie.js to run automated tests for my website. Right now I'm working on automating a person signing up. For the signup a form is used with 3 different divs that look like this

Page Code:

```
<form>
   <div id=step1>
   <div id=step2>
   <div id=step3> 
</form> 
...
...
<button id="nextStep" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" 
   onClick="signupNext()">Cnt. </button>
```

SignupNext is a javascript function which disables the button then some simple things
then re-enables the button.

Zombie Code:

```
browser
   .visit(https://example.com, function(){
     browser.fill(....)
     browser.fill(....)
     browser.pressButton('#nextStep', function(){
        browser.fill(...)
        browser.fill(...)
        browser.pressButton('#nextStep', function(){ //THIS LINE Errors
            ...
            ...
        });
     });
   })
```

Zombie throws the error "Button is disabled" on the second .pressButton. As far as my understanding of zombiejs goes it seems to me like the pressButton should wait for the event to finish then execute the callback function.

*new to zombiejs

Answer (score 1):

**Everythings happen asynchronously** 
From documentation :

> > The browser will load the document and if the document includes any scripts, also load and execute these scripts. It will then process
> >     some events, for example, anything your scripts do on page load. All
> >     of that, just like a real browser, happens asynchronously.
>
> To wait for the page to fully load and process events, you pass visit
>   a callback function. Zombie will then call your callback with null,
>   the browser object, the status code of the last response, and an array
>   of errors (hopefully empty). This is JavaScript, so you don't need to
>   declare all these arguments, and in fact can access them as
>   browser.statusCode and browser.errors.
>
> (Why would the first callback argument be null? It works great when
>   using asynchronous testing frameworks like Mocha
>
> Zombie also supports promises. When you call functions like visit,
>   wait or clickLink without a callback, you get a promise. After the
>   browser is done processing, it either fulfills or rejects the promise.

For example:

```
browser.visit("http://localhost:3000/").
  then(function() {
    assert.equal(browser.text("H1"), "Deferred zombies");
  }).
  fail(function(error) {
    console.log("Oops", error);
  });
```

Comment: Using the promises API Zombie offers, results in the exact same flow of events as using callbacks, but in a neater syntax. This shouldn't change anything that currently breaks.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the way you're checking input to enable/disable this button.
I'm guessing you're probably using either *keyup*, *blur* or both events.
When zombie is filling these inputs for you, it doesn't bother with firing these events as when a real user fills it up using an actual browser, you'll have to use zombie to fire whichever event you need, right after the input is filled up, like this:

```
browser.fill(...);
browser.fill(...);
browser.fire("{checkedInputSelector}", "keyup", function(){
    browser.pressButton('#nextStep', function(){ //THIS LINE shouldn't error anymore
        ...
        ...
    });
});
```